# Laravel Forge fail deploy because of Composer.lock

Tags: git, laravel, merge, web, web-deployment

When clicking deploy, I keep getting the following error messages:

```
    From github.com:my account 
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   40fdcc7..8a338fb  master     -> origin/master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    composer.lock
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I have tried removing composer.lock, gitignore, and composer.lock files as well as doing git check, git stash, composer update and composer install on the server, but none of these commands or removals work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me around this error when deploying [employbl.com](https://employbl.com/) to Laravel Forge:

```
cd /home/forge/employbl.com
git fetch origin master
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
git clean -df
composer install --no-ansi --no-dev --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts --optimize-autoloader
echo "" | sudo -S service php7.2-fpm reload
rm -rf node_modules
```

I believe the issue from the OP comes from a merge conflict that can't be resolved. Those initial git commands effectively wipe what is on the forge server and get the code you want out deployed to the internet!

Answer (score 2):

When you run composer install, composer.lock is generated and lists the exact packages you installed.  You should commit this file.

Then on production, you should run `composer install` instead of `composer update`.  Update re-generates the composer.lock file and causes this issue, whereas `composer install` simply installs the exact packages and versions you installed on your dev site.

Comment: I am getting this same error doing `composer install`. Was the OP running composer update somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

What you can to do is

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Then:

```
git clean -f
```

Answer (score 0):

1. git reset --hard
2. git clean -df
3. composer update

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).